# Chat algorithm with websockets and gcm

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a chat web site and I builded an app of this site.Now my site and app using socket.io(websocket).In current version of my app when user closes the app user can't recevie any message(normally).I decided add GCM support to my app for push notifications.But I have questions about this.

**My scenario:**

- User 1 logged into system from pc then he connected to socket.io
  server and he is waiting messages.
- User 2 logged into system from    android app then he connected to
  socket.io server.
- Now they are chatting with each other.

But 10 minutes later user 2 closed the app and now he won't receive messages.

I am asking what should I do for send push notifications to user 2 ?

I am not asking GCM implemention,I know the GCM implemention.I know the user 2 device id and how can I send push notification to this user.

My problem is:I need to work with socket.io and GCM.How can I detect "okay,user 2 closed the app when user 1 sends a message to user 2 take this message and send to gcm server"

Is this a good approach ? or what do you suggest for like this chat system ? Example you can give an example from Whatsapp how can they handle this problem ? I think they are using Gcm for only push notifications,in app they are using Erlang.

Answer (score 1):

It's not socket.io that connects to the GCM.
You'll need a module for Node.js that enables the connection from the Node.js (running the socket.io) to the GCM. A module like this one [gcm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gcm), there are also examples that can get you started.

So, in your case, you'd want to call `socket.emit()` if the user is online (you should have this already), otherwise the user is offline and you want to push the message by calling `gcm.send()`.

To detect if the user is offline you'd need the to add the user to an offline list when the `socket.on('disconnect',function(){//add user to offline list})` handler is called.